# TYPO3 Content Element in TYPO3 6.0.1

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use the Content Element in my Typoscript. The take a Image from a Folder. I mad this 1000 times in older TYPO3 Versions.

This is mi Code

```
  lib.test = CONTENT
  lib.test{
    table = tt_content
    select{
      uidInList=4
      pidInList=2
    }
  }
```

The Folder ID's are correct.

I mapped the test with Templavoila in a div(inner)

Comment: Why don't you use ``RECORD`` for individual records ``CONTENT`` is for multiple records. Anyway, what kind of content element do you use? Does the mapping work if you use ``lib.test = TEXT`` and ``lib.text.value = test``? Does it work if you remove the ``uidInList = 4`` line? There have not been changes besides ``FAL``, which should not be relevant at this point.

Comment: try to render it directly into the `page.10` instead of to TV and check if your `lib.test` works at all. Note: just suggestion I have no experience with 6.x yet.

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same issue and ported back to Typo3 4.7.x. TemplaVoila and also a lot other extensions still have problems working correctly in 6.x

Answer (score 0):

Try below one;

```
lib.logo = RECORDS 
lib.logo{
          tables = tt_content
          source = 123 #Respected Content Element ID
}
```